# In vb.net, why am I getting a duplicate key error when I have used a revised key?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition and programming in vb.net using ms sql-server 2015. I have set up the data adapter and data table in the form load event. (see below)
        Private m_DABinders As New SqlDataAdapter
    Private m_CBBinders As New SqlCommandBuilder
    Private m_DataTableBinders As New Data.DataTable

I use the code below to insert a row into the Binders table and to check and handle the duplicate key problem. This works fine. My problem comes up when after I get this error, I change the key value to something unique and try to add the row again, and I still get the same duplicate key error, which, strangely enough, shows the original duplicate key value rather than the new one. (I have used MessageBox to ensure that the updated key value is being placed into the appropriate column.) It behaves as if it's still trying to insert the row with the duplicate key before it inserts the updated row.

Do I somehow have to remove the "bad" row from the data adapter or data table after the error? I notice by doing a row count that the rows on the data table goes up by one each time I get this error so I'm thinking I have to delete it somehow but I'm not sure how.

I'm very new to programming in vb.net and with ms sql-server so please don't assume much prior knowledge in your replies. Thanks.

Here is the sub-routine that I use to insert the row.
        Public Sub CreateBinderRow()

```
    Try

        Dim keyValueBinder = tbLocation.Text & tbProject.Text & tbBinder.Text
        Dim drNewBinderRow As DataRow = m_DataTableBinders.NewRow()

        drNewBinderRow("KeyValue") = keyValueBinder
        drNewBinderRow("Location") = tbLocation.Text
        drNewBinderRow("ProjectName") = tbProject.Text
        drNewBinderRow("BinderName") = tbBinder.Text
        drNewBinderRow("LastUpdated") = Now

        m_DataTableBinders.Rows.Add(drNewBinderRow)
        m_DABinders.Update(m_DataTableBinders)

        boolCreateBinderOK = True

    Catch dbException As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        boolCreateBinderOK = False
        MessageBox.Show("SQLException: " & dbException.ToString)
        MessageBox.Show("Error creating Binder row - probably duplicate values", "Binder - Error Creating Binder Row",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    Catch dbException As Exception
        boolCreateBinderOK = False
        MessageBox.Show("SQLException: " & dbException.ToString)
        MessageBox.Show("Error creating Binder row", "Binder - Error Creating Binder Row",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End Try

End Sub
```

BTW - The error I am getting is: SqlException (0x80131904) Violation of Primary Key constraint 'PK.Binders' Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Binders'. The duplicate key value is (my data). The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to [commit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) the changes to the DataTable before updating the 
DataSet.

```
m_DataTableBinders.Rows.Add(drNewBinderRow)
//add this line to commit the changes
m_DataTableBinders.AcceptChanges()
m_DABinders.Update(m_DataTableBinders)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I added the AcceptChanges statement to the Catch sections and it worked perfectly. Thanks again for the quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would not hold a long-term reference to your `DataTable`.

A common code pattern using ADO.NET for database updates looks like:

```
Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("connection string")
    connection.Open
    Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Binders (KeyValue, Location, ProjectName, BinderName, LastUpdated) VALUES (@KeyValue, @Location, @ProjectName, @BinderName, @LastUpdated)", connection)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KeyValue", keyValueBinder)
        '  TODO: Add the rest of the command parameters  '

        command.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. This is an unusual situation where there is only one user on one machine using their own database - nothing shared. With this in mind, I want to reduce the overhead by only opening and closing the connection once.